# Oxyplot in UWP Xamarin not updating

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, oxyplot

I can't seem to bind correctly to Oxyplot in Xamarin. I had a read through multiple posts, but couldn't figure out what's wrong with my setup.

XAML

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<ContentPage.Content>
    
    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="500" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <oxy:PlotView Grid.Row="0" Model="{Binding CandlestickPlotModel}" Background="Green"/>
        
    </Grid>
    
</ContentPage.Content>
```

ViewModel

```
class MainViewModel
{
    public PlotModel CandlestickPlotModel { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        CandlestickPlotModel = new PlotModel();

        CandlestickPlotModel.Title = "Title";
        CandlestickPlotModel.Background = OxyColors.LightBlue;
    }
}
```

When I run, I get a green box, but I would expect a light blue box if the binding would work. Can anyone see what's wrong with this code?

Comment: But you see the title or?

Comment: No, no title either

Comment: Have you tried providing some Height and Width requests to the PlotView, or are you just assuming it will fill whatever area is available?

Comment: I have tried, that doesn't seem to be the issue. I did have a size problem, so I didn't even get a green background. I resolved that, I get a background alright, but the viewmodel doesn't seem to bind properly. I'm starting to wonder if it's a version issue.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Nothing wrong with the Binding. Oxyplot 1.0 and Xamarin Forms and UWP isn't supported. Installing Oxyplot.Xamarin.Forms 1.1.0-unstable fixes the issue.